# Pdf insert leads to only blank pages with pdfpackages

Tags: pdfpages

I have installed the package:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

However when I call on to the function:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample8_1.pdf}
```

It only shows blank pages. This file regards an Excel file which is not something special.

I do not know what the problem is to show the content of the pdfs but it doesn't work. Btw it also does not work pdfs containing images.

Do you guys know by any chance what the problem could be?

this is the code:

```
\chapter{Geotechnical information borrow area}
\label{app:borrowarea}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
   \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
   \includegraphics[width=1.30\textwidth]{figures/1.png}
   \caption{Overview borrow area with soil samples}
   \label{Borrow1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
   \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{figures/2.png}
   \caption{Profiles of soil samples 1}
   \label{Borrow2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{figures/3.png}
   \caption{Profiles of soil samples 2}
   \label{Borrow3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
   \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{figures/4.png}
   \caption{Profiles of soil samples 3}
   \label{Borrow4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
  \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{figures/5.png}
  \caption{Profiles of soil samples 4}
  \label{Borrow5}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\includegraphics{Borrowsoilsample6_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample6_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample8_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample10_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample11_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample11_2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample11_3.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample11_4.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample12.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Borrowsoilsample14.pdf}'
```

This is an appendices file of my bigger file. The output is complete blank for the correct number of pages. There are no white pages in the pdf present.

So to straighten it out, there are no errors given. the pdfs are accepted however they are completely blank. Not even the page numbering is displayed. Hopefully somebody knows the way to fix it!

Comment: Welcome! We need to know something about what is going wrong and about your code. A complete minimal example rather than fragments would be good, but also what you see in the console output and/or log file. Does the PDF include blank pages? Is it in your working directory?

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Like what I now added?

Comment: Hopefully you guys know a solution!

Comment: Can you somehow send the pdf? I had this problem before and the problem lies with the pdf file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 
The code I had worked with another random PDF file (not from Excel), but when I tried to import the Excel-exported PDF there were only blank pages.

I went back to the Excel, exported it without non-printing information (under Options, in the "Publish as PDF" file explorer). It solved it.